# Labelling legend in ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
legendCat<-c('Chemical','Computers & Communications','Drugs & Medical',
  'Electronic & Electrical','Mechanical','Others')
ggplot(cleaned,aes(x=CAT,y=ORIGINAL, fill=as.factor(CAT)))+geom_boxplot()+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(legendCat)))
```

But the labels of the legend are not coming according to the legendCat vector I have defined. How do I do that?

Obtained plot:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = 1:6, labels = legendCat)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a special vector for the legend. Just use:

```
ggplot(cleaned,aes(x=CAT,y=ORIGINAL, fill=as.factor(CAT))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = 1:6, labels = c('Chemical','Computers & Communications','Drugs & Medical','Electronic & Electrical','Mechanical','Others'))
```